# Why can't I strcpy?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, strcpy

For an assignment, I have to make a grade book in C consisting of several interlocking functions. I've gotten through the first few without (too many) headaches, but then there's this thing. Basically, I'm trying to take a character string and copy it into a two-dimensional array inside of a structure. I think I'm on the cusp of success, but the `strcpy` keeps throwing these two charming fellow in my face:

> passing argument 1 of `strcpy` makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> expected 'char **restrict*' but argument is of type 'char'.

Here's my code. `gb` is a pointer pointing to the structure. If I haven't clarified anything enough, please ask.

```
int add_assignment(Gradebook *gb, const char assgn[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS]) {
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; i++) {
    for(j=0; j < (MAX_NAME_LEN+1); j++) {
      strcpy(gb->assignment_names[i][j], assgn);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Here is the Gradebook structure:

```
typedef struct gradebook {
  int number_of_students;
  Students students[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS];
  int number_of_assignments;
  char assignment_names[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS][MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
  int scores[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS][MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS];
} Gradebook;
```

Comment: I assume your assignment_names is a 2d integer array? Use memcpy for non string types. Posting the structure would be nice.

Comment: `strcpy` expects to copy characters into a buffer where you pass the address of the start of the buffer.  It seems , based on the error message, that `gb->assignment_names[i][j]` is not the address of anything.

Comment: It seems weird that you would use `MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS` for the length of the name of an assignment, as well as the maximum count of how many assignments there are.

Comment: Re: MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS: that's just a placeholder. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `Gradebook` structure.

Comment: So gb->assignment_names[i][j] isn't an address? Then what is it? Would it just be the value in assignment_names at Row i, Column j?

Comment: @RubberLotus - We don't know. You haven't shown the structure declaration yet.

Comment: Put the Gradebook structure's code in. Will this do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the use of two loops:

```
for(i=0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; i++) {
  for(j=0; j < (MAX_NAME_LEN+1); j++) {
   strcpy(gb->assignment_names[i][j], assgn);
  }
}
```

The inner loop is trying to copy a string (`assgn`) into a single `char`. You probably meant

```
for(i=0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; i++) {
  strcpy(gb->assignment_names[i], assgn);
}
```

instead, but this may not be what you want either, where one assignment overwrites the entire list of assignments. It's hard to tell what logic you are looking for.

Comment: Heh. I have to admit that I'm learning this as I go along - I have a general idea of what I want, but my grasp of how to implement it is even weaker than I thought aaaand your respect for me is probably dropping with each word.

Comment: But seriously, thanks for the help. I'll try all your advice right now.

Answer (score 1):

`assignment_names[i][j]` is a single character, not a string. `assignment_names[i]` is a character array, so you should copy to that. You don't need the inner loop.

```
int add_assignment(Gradebook *gb, const char assgn[]) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; i++) {
       strcpy(gb->assignment_names[i], assgn);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It seems unclear why a function named `add_assignment ` would change the name of every single assignment